# Winsock Send Function

Tags: winsock, file-transfer

so this is a pretty basic concept question, but I'm new to this.  I have successfully opened and connected a socket between my Windows computer and my Ubuntu lamp server.  I want to send a .txt file through this socket onto the server via the Winsock Send function.  Where do I tell the socket/send function which folder to put the location in? When I connected to the server, I just gave an IP address and port (ex:// `192.168.1.25` over port `80`) and made the connection.  Is there a way to tell it to put it in a specific location, like `/var/local/storage/folder`? I didn't see anything in either the send function of socket connection that specified an ending location?

Sorry if this is a newbie question. thanks in advance.